# How do I convert a string to this format? pgAdmin claims this is a "byte array" but is it really?

Tags: arrays, string, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a public key stored in a database, which is stored as `02fa6902e91e127d6d3410f6abc271a79ae24029079caa0db5819757e3c1c1c5a4`. In a different part of the database, that same data as instead stored as "binary data" with the type "bytea". In pgAdmin III, and *ONLY* in pgAdmin III and *ONLY* when I run a query grabbing the row using another column, the data is returned as follows:

`\002\372i\002\351\036\022}m4\020\366\253\302q\247\232\342@)\007\234\252\015\265\201\227W\343\301\301\305\244`

I need to query for this specific "binary data" to pull up said rows in other parts of my code. However, I have never seen this data format before, it doesn't show up in pgAdmin4 even when I run a query on other columns (it shows up as "binary data" instead without the data above being shown). Querying using the weird format above gets me the data I want, but I have multiple public key strings that I need to convert to the odd format above, and I'm clueless as to how to go about doing this. It doesn't seem to be like any byte array I've ever seen.

Comment: `row using another column` what query are you running?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Manual looking using an ID for a specific row. Not feasible to use it in actual production. This works for obtaining public keys one at a time but not when we need to work on lots or all the sets at once.

Comment: Sorry don't know what that mean. You were talking about a query but i don't see one. You say some query doesnt work in pgAdmin but work in somewhere else. The same data is also store in two different table using different data type. You should provide both table structure and the query.

Comment: The query works fine. The pgAdmin client just doesn't display the data, it simply shows `[binary data]` when ran in pgAdmin 4 but displays the string I need in pgAdmin III.

Comment: Ok, And what is the problem then?

Comment: I have large sets of data and manually referencing via another column is not feasible. I need to convert the public key to the format of the second string but I do not understand how `02fa6902e91e127d6d3410f6abc271a79ae24029079caa0db5819757e3c1c1c5a4` becomes `\002\372i\002\351\036\022}m4\020\366\253\302q\247\232\342@)\007\234\252\015\265\201\227W\343\301\301\305\244`. I need a way to convert the data.

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

. I know is there some binary issue. But what are you trying to do? Copy / Paste from the pgAdmin result ? What mean convert? From where to where?

Comment: I need to know how to turn `02fa6902e91e127d6d3410f6abc271a79ae24029079caa0db5819757e3c1‌​c1c5a4` into `\002\372i\002\351\036\022}m4\020\366\253\302q\247\232\342@)\‌​007\234\252\015\265\‌​201\227W\343\301\301‌​\305\244` so I can do it with other data. That's the problem.

Comment: The first string represents a byte array using two hex digits per byte. The second string represents the same byte array using `\nnn` for unprintable characters, where nnn is in octal, or the ASCII character representation if the byte is printable. I expect you don't actually need to convert it into the second string, but pass the value as a `byte[]` array.

Comment: Again what mean other data? What you want do with that? You say display in pgAdmin ? Looks like you are just confused on what that mean.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thank you! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The two values are the same.

The difference is that the first representation is in hexadecimal (there should be a `\x` at the beginning), while in the second representation every non-ASCII byte is represented as `\xxx` with `xxx` being the octal value of the byte.

The first representation is the "modern" one, while the second was used in old PostgreSQL versions.

I suspect that your pgAdmin III is not the latest version.

Comment: Yes, that describes it pretty neatly.